# Why are goGTK widgets not initialized in the init() function?

Tags: go, gtk, gtk3, init

I am using Go 1.21.4 on a Windows 11 Pro machine and GTK 3 binding for Go.

Simple sample code:

```
package GTKView

import (

    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"
)

var mToolbar *gtk.Toolbar

func initGtkWidgets() {

    mToolbar, _ = gtk.ToolbarNew()

}

func InitGUI(Win *gtk.Window, fp func(*gtk.TextBuffer)) {

    initGtkWidgets()
    mToolbar.SetHAlign(gtk.ALIGN_START)

}
```

**This code works:** `InitGUI()` is called from `main()` to initialize the GTK GUI. `mToolbar` is initialized with the call to `initGtkWidgets()` , and  `mToolbar.SetHAlign` executes properly.

However, the following code, relying on `init()` to initialize `mToolbar`, compiles, but **fails at runtime** with a string of errors and memory addresses, apparently because `mToolbar` was not initialized by `init()` when `InitGUI()` was called from `main()` .

```
package GTKView

import (

    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"
)

var mToolbar *gtk.Toolbar

func init() {

    mToolbar, _ = gtk.ToolbarNew()

}

func InitGUI(Win *gtk.Window, fp func(*gtk.TextBuffer)) {

    mToolbar.SetHAlign(gtk.ALIGN_START)
 
}

I come from a C++ and Object Pascal background. 
My understanding is that Go's `init()` 
is similar to the `initialization` section of an Object Pascal unit: 
Runs once, automatically, before code in the unit itself is called, 
and it's possible to initialize exposed variables in the `initialization` section.

Why aren't widgets initialized properly in Go, using `init()`?

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi
  [3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal
```

Comment: The `init()` function is called during package initialization.  See the [specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Package_initialization) and [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#init).

Comment: [init() works just as you expect](https://go.dev/play/p/xzNoGk2Jla8).  "Why aren't the widgets initialized properly with `init()`?"  You're ignoring error returns from `ToolbarNew` and `BoxNew`.   It's a bad idea to ignore errors in Go: since it doesn't have exceptions, error return values are the *only* chance you have to notice there's an error.

Comment: @erik258 _error return values are the only chance you have to notice there's an error_ - I noticed them, as stated in the question - in all their length - without checking for them. And in init() they also wouldn't have shown up until runtime. Regardless, this is only test code - in **important** situations, I would certainly examine an error.

Comment: @erik258 - based on what Cerise Limón has cited, init() doesn't work at all as I expected - there are no _initialization dependencies_  in Object Pascal's initialization section. For that reason  init() doesn't initialize those widgets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [***Cerise Limón***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%C3%B3n) for pointing me in the right direction:

[Package initialization](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Package_initialization)

> More precisely, a package-level variable is considered ready for
> initialization if it is not yet initialized and either has no
> initialization expression or **its initialization expression has no
> dependencies on uninitialized variables**.

The GTK widgets are written in C, and in their constructors the widgets are initialized using pointers with the `new` operator. Although the documentation refers to initialization expressions outside of `init()`, it appears that the GTK widgets. although they are included in `init()`, are also ***not ready for initialization because of dependencies on uninitialized variables,*** and were not initialized in the call to `InitGUI()` when relying on `init()`.